# Can app.UseErrorHandler() access error details?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my MVC4 app I had a global.asax.cs override of `Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)` where I could extract the `exception`, `statusCode` and `requestedUrl` (for handling 404). That would get sent to my controller and the error page would be different for 404s vs 5xx (these get a stack trace). I don't see how to get this same info to my Error action using `UseErrorHandler()`. Am I using the right approach in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Aug. 02th 2016 - Update for 1.0.0

**Startup.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;

namespace NS
{
    public class Startup
    {
         ...
         public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
         {
             ...
             app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
             ...
         }
     }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace NS.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        static ILogger _logger;
        public HomeController(ILoggerFactory factory)
        {
            if (_logger == null)
                _logger = factory.Create("Unhandled Error");
        }

        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
            var error = feature?.Error;
            _logger.LogError("Oops!", error);
            return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml", error);
        }
    }
}
```

**project.json**

```
...
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
     ...
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks. That works for 500 style errors.  But unfortunately not for 404 errors.  Guess I need another mechanism to handle 404 errors.

Comment: Do you read [samples on diagnostic on github](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/tree/dev/samples) ? I think the [StatucCodeSample](https://github.com/aspnet/Diagnostics/blob/dev/samples/StatusCodePagesSample/Startup.cs) can be help full

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Still learning my way around all the .NET assets on GitHub.  :-)

Comment: @aguafrommars I am on RC1 but when I copy your Controller code into mine both `Context` and `IErrorHandlerFeature` are not recognized and Intillisense does not suggest any `using` statement to add. My `project.json` does have the same dependency you listed. Is this answer no longer valid or is there something not listed that I am missing?

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete, this answer should be valid for RC1, you can check on my sample on [github repo](https://github.com/aguacongas/chatle). Maybe there's another issue in you code. Is your controller derive from `Controller` ?

Comment: @aguafrommars It does look like this answer is out dated. If you look at your `HomeController` you use this line in it `this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();` Which work for me after adding `using Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics;` and `using Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features;`

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete oh yes, you're right, I'm going to update my answer thx

Comment: I had to include `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features` as a package to work properly

Answer (score 4):

In Beta8, agua from mars' answer is a little different.

Instead of:

```
var feature = Context.GetFeature<IErrorHandlerFeature>();
```

Use:

```
var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
```

This also requires a reference to Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features, and the following line in Configure() in Startup.cs:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
```

Answer (score 1):

From your configured error handling action, you could do something like:

```
public IActionResult Error()
{
    // 'Context' here is of type HttpContext
    var feature = Context.GetFeature<IErrorHandlerFeature>();
    if(feature != null)
    {
        var exception = feature.Error;
    }
......
.......
```

Comment: I need to mess with this some more but right now, I can't even get UseErrorHandler to invoke my action. Sigh..

Comment: Me also - it doesn't invoke action /home/error. I have

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRuntimeInfoPage();

            app.UseErrorHandler("/Home/Error");

I can open /home/error directly

Comment: @ChrisHarrington: You need to register `UseErrorHandler` as the first middleware in the pipeline

Comment: var feature = Context.GetFeature<IErrorHandlerFeature>();
it is showing null value in variable why?

Comment: `IErrorHandlerFeature` isn't recognized in my project. Where is it located?