# How to handle errors with para in Asp Net Core?

Tags: error-handling, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

In the manual, it says I can redirect my page to an error page by:

```
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

For example, in a controller class I wrote:

```
public IActionResult test(){
    throw new Exception("Some Para");
    var obj = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    return new ObjectResult(obj);
}
```

As you can see, I did send para when I triggered the exception. **But how could I get the para in my ErrorController**? Now it looks like this:

```
public class ErrorController : Controller
{

    //In the tutorial, this can be public static void HomePage(IApplicationBuilder app)
    //But failed when i tried
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(){
        var obj = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        obj.Add("error","code");
        return new ObjectResult(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can ASP.NET 5 app.UseErrorHandler() access error details?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385246/can-asp-net-5-app-useerrorhandler-access-error-details)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30385246/can-asp-net-5-app-useerrorhandler-access-error-details - but your question isn't very clear.